# Disabling buttons on react native

Tags: react-native

I'm making an android app using react native and I've used TouchableOpacity component to create buttons.
I use a text input component to accept text from the user and the button should **only be enabled** once the text input matches a certain string.
I can think of a way to do this by initially rendering the button without the TouchableOpactiy wrapper and re-rendering with the wrapper once the input string matches.
But I'm guessing there is a much better way to do this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 428, accepted):

`TouchableOpacity` extends `TouchableWithoutFeedback`, so you can just use the `disabled` property :

```
<TouchableOpacity disabled={true}>
  <Text>I'm disabled</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

[React Native TouchableWithoutFeedback #disabled documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#disabled)

The new [Pressable](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable#disabled) API has a `disabled` option too :

```
<Pressable disabled={true}>
  {({ pressed }) => (
    <Text>I'm disabled</Text>
  )}
</Pressable>
```

Comment: Well do you have anything that might give an hint on what it's not working for you ? What version of RN do you use ? Can you show us some code ?

Just a link to the RN documentation to help you: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#disabled

Comment: Notice the `disabled` state doesn't change child rendering styles so in order to make the disabled state visible to users you would need to apply a style to the `Text` element such as `<Text style={{ opacity: 0.5 }}>I'm disabled</Text>` -- just a FYI

Comment: In addition to what Peter has suggested here, you can also change the opacity level for the button when the touch is active (defaults to `0.2` for now). https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity#activeopacity

Answer (score 60):

Just do this

```
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={disabled ? 1 : 0.7} onPress={!disabled && onPress}>
  <View>
    <Text>{text}</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: `<Text>{text}</FontText>`? FontText?

Comment: onPress is not expecting a boolean

Comment: second press gives this error. `TypeError: onPress is not a function. (In 'onPress(event)', 'onPress' is false)`
Solution not recommended.

Answer (score 7):

this native-base there is solution:

```
<Button
    block
    disabled={!learnedWordsByUser.length}
    style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
    onPress={learnedWordsByUser.length && () => {
      onFlipCardsGenerateNewWords(learnedWordsByUser)
      onFlipCardsBtnPress()
    }}
>
    <Text>Let's Review</Text>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 5):

So it is very easy to disable any button in react native

```
<TouchableOpacity disabled={true}>
    <Text> 
          This is disabled button
   </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**disabled** is a prop in react native and when you set its value to "true" it will disable your button

Happy Cooding

Answer (score 4):

This seems like the kind of thing that could be solved using a Higher Order Component. I could be wrong though because I'm struggling to understand it 100% myself, but maybe it'll be helpful to you (here's a couple links)...

- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2888-experimenting-with-higher-order-components-in-reactjs.htm
- http://jamesknelson.com/structuring-react-applications-higher-order-components/

Answer (score 3):

TouchableOpacity receives `activeOpacity`. You can do something like this

```
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={enabled ? 0.5 : 1}>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

So if it's enabled, it will look normal, otherwise, it will look just like touchablewithoutfeedback.

Comment: But that still doesn't disable it. Just doesn't change opacity on touch.

Comment: You could do something like onPress={@someMethod if enabled}.
In this way, you won't have to wrap your view in different views or touchables.

Answer (score 2):

To disable Text you have to set the opacity:0 in Text style like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{opacity:0}}>
  <Text>I'm disabled</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the disabled prop in TouchableOpacity when your input does not match the string

```
<TouchableOpacity disabled = { stringMatched ? false : true }>
    <Text>Some Text</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

where stringMatched is a state.

Answer (score 1):

You can build an CustButton with [`TouchableWithoutFeedback`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#props), and set the effect and logic you want with `onPressIn`, `onPressout` or other props.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by putting a conditional in the style property.

```
const startQuizDisabled = () => props.deck.cards.length === 0;

<TouchableOpacity
  style={startQuizDisabled() ? styles.androidStartQuizDisable : styles.androidStartQuiz}
  onPress={startQuiz}
  disabled={startQuizDisabled()}
>
  <Text 
    style={styles.androidStartQuizBtn} 
  >Start Quiz</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
androidStartQuiz: {
    marginTop:25,
    backgroundColor: "green",
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1
},
androidStartQuizDisable: {
    marginTop:25,
    backgroundColor: "green",
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    opacity: 0.4
},
androidStartQuizBtn: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 24
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most efficient way is to wrap the touchableOpacity with a view and add the prop pointerEvents with a style condition.

```
<View style={this.state.disabled && commonStyles.buttonDisabled}        
      pointerEvents={this.state.disabled ? "none" : "auto"}>
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.connectButton}>
  <Text style={styles.connectButtonText}">CONNECT </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

CSS:

```
buttonDisabled: {
    opacity: 0.7
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my work around for this I hope it helps :

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
        this.onSubmit()
    }}
    disabled={this.state.validity}
    style={this.state.validity ?
          SignUpStyleSheet.inputStyle :
          [SignUpStyleSheet.inputAndButton, {opacity: 0.5}]}>
    <Text style={SignUpStyleSheet.buttonsText}>Sign-Up</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

in `SignUpStyleSheet.inputStyle` holds the style for the button when it disabled or not, then in `style={this.state.validity ? SignUpStyleSheet.inputStyle : [SignUpStyleSheet.inputAndButton, {opacity: 0.5}]}` I add the opacity property if the button is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable and disable button or by using condition or directly  by default it will be disable : true

```
 // in calling function of button 
    handledisableenable()
        {
         // set the state for disabling or enabling the button
           if(ifSomeConditionReturnsTrue)
            {
                this.setState({ Isbuttonenable : true })
            }
          else
          {
             this.setState({ Isbuttonenable : false})
          }
        }

<TouchableOpacity onPress ={this.handledisableenable} disabled= 
     {this.state.Isbuttonenable}>

    <Text> Button </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use disabled true property

```
<TouchableOpacity disabled={true}> </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution ever:

You can add **onPressOut** event to the **TouchableOpcaity**
and do whatever you want to do.
It will not let user to press again until **onPressOut** is done

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since Fomahaut already mentioned that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation.