# React-native- conditionally Disable TouchableHighlight if array is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to `disable TouchableHighlight` if my array is empty and turn it back to `enable` if my array has value.

```
this.state = {
     modalVisible: false,
     array:[],
    }
  }

toggleModal(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible})
    }

<TouchableHighlight
 underlayColor="transparent"
 onPress = {() => {
 if(this.state.array == undefined || this.state.array.length == 0){
 this.toggleModal(this.state.modalVisible)}
 else {
 this.toggleModal(!this.state.modalVisible)}
}}>
<Text>close</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Above is my code. I think I have it right but its not working. Any advise or comments would be really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling buttons on react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407665/disabling-buttons-on-react-native)

Comment: You can use that duplicate link and set your `disabled` condition to `this.state.array.length === 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
this.state =
{
    modalVisible: false,
    array:  []
}

toggleModal = visible => this.setState({modalVisible: visible})

render = () =>
{
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight
            underlayColor="transparent"
            disabled={this.state.array.length === 0}
            onPress = {() =>
            {
                if(this.state.array == undefined || this.state.array.length == 0)
                    this.toggleModal(this.state.modalVisible);
                else
                    this.toggleModal(!this.state.modalVisible);
            }}>
            <Text>close</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
    );
}
```