# How do I conditionally disable a row in a ListView component as if it were a button?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am going through our mobile app (React Native 0.41.2) and setting the buttons to be disabled conditionally based upon the state of the component it is in. This is a simple task with a real `<Button />` component, because that component takes a prop, `disabled`, and based upon the boolean value passed to it, the button is either disabled or not. The purpose of disabling the buttons is to prevent the user from pressing a button multiple times, which can cause issues. So, I have been able to easily control the `<Button />` components, but now I am having a problem coming up with a similar strategy to disable the rows of a `<ListView />` component. As far as I can tell there is no prop such as `disabled` that can tell the row to disable being pressed. I have read a lot of posts about how to delete rows, however I just need to disable the row, as in a press to the row will result in nothing.

I am rendering a list of projects as the dataSource. Each row is a Project component, and pressing the row takes the user to the Project screen. I have tried wrapping the Project component in a `<TouchableOpacity/>` component, because I know that component takes the `disabled` prop. [I found this approach here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407665/disabling-buttons-on-react-native)

```
<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    enableEmptySections={true}
    renderRow={(project) =>
      <TouchableOpacity disabled={true}> 
        <Project 
         project={project} 
         isLoggingIn={this.state.isLoggingIn}
         navigation={this.props.navigation} 
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
     }
 />
```

I would expect that the above code would render a `<Project />` row that is disabled, however the row is not disabled. Even after passing a hardcoded value of `true` to the `disabled` prop, I can still press it and it takes me to the Project screen. Please advise.

Comment: What might be the most straightforward approach is to modify your Project component and add a `disabled` prop  which, when set to true, will cause the style to change and prevent it from navigating/selecting/whatever the list item does.

Comment: @Kai - Thanks! That makes sense.