# how to prevent onPress event in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I prevent function for onPress from running when onLongPress is triggered. Current when I long press after releasing the button onPress is still triggered.

```
const _handleOnpress =()=>{
  console.log('onPressed triggered')
  // other task only for onPress event
}

const _handleLongPress =()=>{
  console.log('LongPress triggered')
  // other task only for onLongPress event
}

return(
  <Pressable
    onPress={_handleOnpress}
    onLongPress={_handleLongPress}
  >
    <Text>Press me</Text>
  </Pressable>
)
```

Comment: I think this answer might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36309491/13719014

Comment: I want to disable the onPress function when the button is longpress

Answer (score 2):

When the button is longpress, the onPress function won't be triggered.

But if you want to disabled the onPress function once onLongPress function is triggered, you can set a state to disabled it. Eg:

```
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

const _handleOnpress =()=>{
  if(!disabled){
    console.log('onPressed triggered')
    // other task only for onPress event
  }
}

const _handleLongPress =()=>{
  console.log('LongPress triggered')
  setDisabled(true);
  // other task only for onLongPress event
}
```